Bluetooth headset - no sound after switching out of mSBC codec and back
I have this strange issue for a while now, (ubuntu 22.04 at least), when connecting my bluetooth headphones (Sony MDR-1000X, but I have the same issue with the Sony WH-1000X M3):
I can use the HSP/HFP profile with the mSBC codec exactly once. If I switch out of it for another profile then go back to it, no sound will be heard in the headphones. The mic won't work either. Any other profile, HSP/HFP with the CVSD codec, or any A2DP profile, work perfectly fine. The issue is only with the mSBC codec and only after I've switched out of it.
What is stranger is that the sound output bar in both gnome settings and pavucontrol behave as if sound is coming out.
I've managed to catch the following logs as well :
juin 01 10:43:16 zaf-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: corrupted SCO packet
juin 01 10:43:16 zaf-desktop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: corrupted SCO packet
juin 01 10:43:27 zaf-desktop rtkit-daemon[2367]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
juin 01 10:43:27 zaf-desktop rtkit-daemon[2367]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 1 users.
 juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop gsd-media-keys[3438]: Unable to get default source
juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop gsd-media-keys[3438]: Unable to get default sink
juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop pipewire-pulse[2888]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x5598ae2ccdb0 [GNOME Settings]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:4294967295 error:25 (Input/output error)
juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop pipewire-pulse[2888]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x5598ae2ccdb0 [GNOME Settings]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:4294967295 error:25 (Input/output error)
juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop gsd-media-keys[3438]: Unable to get default sink
juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop gsd-media-keys[3438]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop gsd-media-keys[3438]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop gsd-media-keys[3438]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop gsd-media-keys[3438]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop gsd-media-keys[3438]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop gsd-media-keys[3438]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop gsd-media-keys[3438]: gvc_mixer_card_get_index: assertion 'GVC_IS_MIXER_CARD (card)' failed
juin 01 10:44:17 zaf-desktop pipewire-pulse[2888]: mod.protocol-pulse: client 0x5598ae2ccdb0 [GNOME Settings]: ERROR command:-1 (invalid) tag:639 error:25 (Input/output error)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated, mSBC is a much cleaner codec when I'm in a call and I'd like to be able to use my headset for that again.
Please let me know if I can provide more information.
